# Is function scope variable not writable

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
function add() {
    var counter = 0;
    counter += 1;
    return counter
}
```

Why the counter variable dont get incremented after first iteration? output is always `1`.

Comment: Because you initialize it at 0 every time... The code does exactly what you think it does.

Comment: You declare a new `counter` variable within and always set it to 0. Every time you call this function, it will always reset to 0 and increment by 1, then return 1

Comment: why the new state of variable counter isn't saved after re assignment of variable

Comment: OP modeled a useless machine in javascript :)

Answer (score 6):

The `add`function is returning the variable `counter` which is defined inside the function `add`. The scope of variable `counter` is local to function, which means each time you invoke the function, it creates a new variable `counter` and then initialize to zero and then increment the counter.

If you are looking for a counter implementation, then you need to reference the same `counter` variable every time and increment that variable. This can be implemented by using closure.

**Example:** In the below example, there are 2 functions, 1 nested inside the another one. The inner function maintains a reference to the outer function Environment, which in this case contains the `counter` variable. So, even after the control moves out of the function add, the inner functions maintains a reference to `counter` variable.

```js
var add = (function(){
  var counter = 0;
  return function(){
    return ++counter;
  }
})();

document
  .querySelector('#btn')
  .addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.querySelector('#output').textContent = add();
  });
```

```html
<div id="output">0</div>
<button id="btn">Increment</button>
```

Comment: @JeremyThille Which is a closure, as Agalo said. A closure utilizes variables declared in a parent scope.

Comment: `var counter; function add(){counter += 1; return counter;}` and `(function(){ var counter = 0; return function add(){counter += 1; return counter;};}())`

Comment: why the code above doesn't work when is used as function definition instead of expression and also i am not clear .. by above explanation is it that once the function is declared all its variable assignment can't be changed by its invocation true ?

Comment: I suggest you read more about how the scope works in javascript. Your code wouldn't work even if it is function expression. If the variable is declared inside the function, it will create a new variable everytime. In the code posted in my answer, the `add()` function returns *another* function which is the inner function. So, when we call `add()` again the function wouldn't execute the line `var counter = 0;` instead it executes the returned function which contains the code `return ++counter;`. I hope it brings more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the counter a global variable and then call the add function:

```
function add(){  
  counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping issue. Change it to

```
let counter = 0;
function add() {
    counter += 1;
    return counter
}
```

Or if you want to be able to do add(), use a nested function

```
function adder() {
  let counter = 0;
  return function plus() {
    return counter += 1;
  };
}
let add = adder();
console.log(add());
console.log(add());
console.log(add());
```